Why properties initializing don't propagate to child class in ECMASCRIPT?
I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around inheritance in ES6 classes. Searching here, most of the answers are 10+ years old so I don't think they apply still. Let's start with the sample code:


class BaseClass {
    baseUnitializedProp;
    baseInitializedProp = 'abc';
    constructor(properties) {
        Object.assign(this, properties);
        console.log('--- BaseClass Constructor ---');
        console.log(this);
        return this;
    }    
}
    
class ClassWithProp extends BaseClass {
    childUnitializedProp;
    childInitializedProp = 1;
}
    
class ClassWithOwnAssign extends ClassWithProp {
    constructor(properties) {
        const instance = super();
        Object.assign(this, properties);
        return instance;
    }    
}
    
const initedObj = new ClassWithProp({
    childInitializedProp: 20, 
    childUnitializedProp: 10, 
    baseUnitializedProp: 15
});
    
console.log('--- Post initialization ---');
console.log(initedObj);
    
const assignedObj = new ClassWithOwnAssign({
    childInitializedProp: 20, 
    childUnitializedProp: 10, 
    baseUnitializedProp: 15
});
console.log('--- Post initialization ---');
console.log(assignedObj);



My question is, why don't the child properties assignment propagate? From the console.log inside the constructor you see that the properties were assigned, but outside the same properties end up with the declared initial value (or undefined).

You need to pass the properties to the superclass constructor: super(properties)

There's no need to assign or return instance. It automatically operates on this.

Even without it, it does not work. My issues is that, for example, take the childInitializedProp property on ClassWithProp, After using Object.assign  on BaseClass.constructor, inside the constructor it shows the correct value, but outside it is still the default.

Now I see what you're doing. I think this is related to how it combines the property initializations in the class with the constructor.

While questions about very specific behavior are totally a thing, I hope you and anyone else reading this would know better than to actually write code like this...

"Most of the answers are 10+ years old so I don't think they apply still" - why wouldn't they? Which answers did you find? Please link them.

@bergi Because they were for pre ES6, the code still had the old when to create 'classes' by called a function and then changing the prototype.

The order of execution

Child constructor is called if any, but you are forced to call the base's class constructor with super() if any to work with this
Base class declared props are initialized (assigned to this)
Base class constructor is called if any
Child class declared props are initialized (assigned to this)
Child class constructor is executed after super() (if any)

In your first case the properties that you pass are gone into the base class constructor and assigned to this, but then overridden by the declared properties in the child class.
In your second case you don't pass any properties to the base constructor so it shows only declared initialized base class properties, than you assign all properties in the child constructor.
In this design pattern you can control the assignment precisely: in each constructor you can assign only props that belongs to the constructor's class. Any non declared in the classes props are skipped. I liked this one (made it right now):


class BaseClass {
    #props = new Set;
    baseUnitializedProp;
    baseInitializedProp = 'abc';
    constructor(properties) {
        console.log('--- BaseClass Init ---');
        console.log(this);
        this.init(properties);
        console.log('--- BaseClass Constructor ---');
        console.log(this);
    }
    init(properties){
      for(const k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)){
        if(k in properties && !this.#props.has(k)){
          this[k] = properties[k];
          this.#props.add(k);
        }
      }
    }
}
    
class ClassWithProp extends BaseClass {
    childUnitializedProp;
    childInitializedProp = 1;
    constructor(properties){
      console.log('--- ClassWithProp Constructor called ---');
      super(properties);
      console.log('--- ClassWithProp Init ---');
      console.log(this);      
      this.init(properties);
      console.log('--- ClassWithProp Constructor after super() ---');
      console.log(this);
    }
}
    
const initedObj = new ClassWithProp({
    childInitializedProp: 20, 
    childUnitializedProp: 10, 
    baseUnitializedProp: 15,
    iAmDummyPleaseSkipMe: 'skipped'
});
    
console.log('--- Post initialization ---');
console.log(initedObj);
.as-console-wrapper{max-height: 100% !important}




So, the only to not have to copy the Object.assign is using an init function to be called AFTER new?

@Sol i've made a solution/design pattern to control the order of assignments so they would go in order with the declared props' initializations

How does step 2 happen before step 4? Isn't the base class constructor called when the child constructor calls super()?

@Barmar, yes i forget to mention the use of super but it's hard to explain, you have to call super anyway to work with this, so it looks like the base constructor is called first anyway

But if the child contructor does anything before calling super(), you'll see that step 4 happens before step 2. E.g. console.log("starting child constructor"); super(properties); other stuff; console.log("finished child constructor");

@Sol You can also write class ClassWithProp extends BaseClass { childUnitializedProp = this.childUnitializedProp; childInitializedProp = this.childInitializedProp ?? 1; }. But yeah, generally the parent constructor has no business in initialising properties of the child class. Write a constructor for the child class if it should receive arguments to initialise its properties with.

@bergi Thank you. I went with the init() solution and calling it after doing a new.
